# Not able to filter records based on date filter in Informix

Tags: datetime, informix

I want to put filter on an Informix query:

```
WHERE agentstatedetail.eventdatetime < '1753-01-01 00:00:00' - INTERVAL(3) DAY TO DAY
```

but it fails ...
Please tell where it goes wrong.

Comment: I'll experiment later with what's up with the notation you're using, but using `DATETIME(1753-01-01 00:00:00) YEAR TO SECOND` should get your show back on the road.

Answer (score 2):

As noted in a comment, the solution is to ensure that the string is interpreted as a `DATETIME` value.  The simple way to do that is to use the `DATETIME` literal notation:

```
DATETIME(1753-01-01 00:00:00) YEAR TO SECOND
```

To demonstrate:

```
CREATE TABLE agentstatedetail
(
    eventdatetime DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    eventname VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO agentstatedetail VALUES('1752-12-25 12:00:00', 'Christmas Day, Noon, 1752');
INSERT INTO agentstatedetail VALUES('1752-12-31 12:00:00', 'New Year''s Eve, Noon, 1752');
INSERT INTO agentstatedetail VALUES('1753-01-01 12:00:00', 'New Year''s Day, Noon, 1753');

SELECT * FROM agentstatedetail WHERE agentstatedetail.eventdatetime < '1753-01-01 00:00:00' - INTERVAL(3) DAY TO DAY;
```

This is your original WHERE clause embedded into a minimal SELECT statement.  It yields the error:

```
SQL -1261: Too many digits in the first field of datetime or interval.
```

(NB: It would have been helpful to include the error message in the question.)

Here's an alternative version of the query, with the `DATETIME` literal in place:

```
SELECT * FROM agentstatedetail
    WHERE agentstatedetail.eventdatetime < DATETIME(1753-01-01 00:00:00) YEAR TO SECOND -
                                           INTERVAL(3) DAY TO DAY
;
```

Output from the sample data:

```
1752-12-25 12:00:00|Christmas DAY, Noon, 1752
```

I observe that the value calculated is a constant; you could rewrite the code as:

```
SELECT * FROM agentstatedetail
    WHERE agentstatedetail.eventdatetime < DATETIME(1752-12-29 00:00:00) YEAR TO SECOND
```

I suspect that the value is passed as a parameter somewhere along the line.

Alternatively, you can cast the string to a DATETIME value and you'd get the same result:

```
SELECT * FROM agentstatedetail
    WHERE agentstatedetail.eventdatetime < CAST('1753-01-01 00:00:00' AS DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND) -
                                           INTERVAL(3) DAY TO DAY
;
```

or:

```
SELECT * FROM agentstatedetail
    WHERE agentstatedetail.eventdatetime < '1753-01-01 00:00:00'::DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND -
                                           INTERVAL(3) DAY TO DAY
```